# Responsive Divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need a 3 or 4 column responsive div system. Reading some question here I found [this snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/JF2gG/):

HTML:

```
<div class="core">
 <div class="box">
  <div class="text">Text</div>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
  <div class="text">Text</div>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
  <div class="text">Text</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.core {width: 100%; display: table; border-spacing: 10px;}

.box{
    background-color: coral;
    width: 32.03125%; 
    float:none;
    display: table-cell;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.text{
    padding: 10px;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
}
```

which is basically what I need and what I already have. The problem is when the with gets smaller I want it to get the blocks down, like a paragraph.

Instead of this:

[image]

I want this:

[image]

Comment: if no media queries then js is the only way to go i reckon.

Comment: Ok then lets go with media queries

Comment: btw, a flexbox should be a much better (or at least more snazzy) solution than what you have atm. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS:

```
.core {width: 100%; display: table; border-spacing: 10px;}

.box{
    background-color: coral;
    width: 100%; 
    float:none;
    display: table-row;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.text{
    padding: 10px;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
}
```

---

> The problem is when the with get's smaller I want it to get the blocks
>   down

This link you found is not using any responsive frameworks. It's just simple CSS + HTML